# Argument of complex number with natural number k

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have the complex number `(1 - E^2) (2 + I 2 Pi k)` with `k` a natural number. How can I get the general formula for the argument? It should be `Pi + ArcTan[k Pi]`.

I tried with:

```
Assumptions->Element[k,Integers]
Assumptions -> k > 0
Arg[(1 - E^2) (2 + 2 I Pi k)]
```

but it does not work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following gets close:

```
ComplexExpand[
    Arg[(1-E^2) (2+2 I Pi k)],
    TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}
]
```

> ArcTan[-2, -2 k π]

Comment: Hi @CarlWoll. What does the comma mean?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Look it up [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan). Basically, `ArcTan[x, y]` is the same as `ArcTan[y/x]` except that the signs of `x` and `y` are used to determine the appropriate quadrant.

Comment: @Gennaro, you might meet it a lot of times in future work, so you might as well learn about [two-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: @CarlWoll the only strange thing is that real part $\frac{1-e^2}{2+2\pi^2 k^2}<0$ and imaginary part $\frac{\pi k(e^2-1)}{2+2\pi^2 k^2}>0$, thus I expect the result Pi+ArcTan[-2,-2 k Pi].

Comment: Thank you @J.M. In Mathematica ArcTan does not implement atan2 because, as you can see above, real<0 and imaginary>0 don't add +Pi to ArcTan.

Comment: @Gennaro, I daresay that I don't quite understand what you mean. To use a concrete example, `ArcTan[-Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2]` and `Arg[(I - Sqrt[3])/2]` both return the expected result. Compare the result of those two with `ArcTan[1/2/(-Sqrt[3]/2)].` (You might wish to note that *Mathematica*'s argument order for two-argument arctangent is the reverse of most other languages like Fortran.)

Comment: @Gennaro The imaginary part of `(1 - E^2) (2 + I 2 Pi k)` is less than 0 for $k>0$, isn't it?

Comment: @J.M. For example ArcTan[1, -1 ]=-pi/4, but the correct result is Arg[-1 + I]=3pi/4. Is it possible to obtain atan2 in Mathematica?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Like I said earlier, the syntax in Mathematica is `ArcTan[x, y]`. So, in Mathematica, `ArcTan[1, -1]` corresponds to `Arg[1 - I]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll The problem is that the result is different: -pi/4 and 3pi/4.

Comment: @Gennaro, read the last sentence of my previous comment a bit more carefully and slowly. Then evaluate `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[a + b I] == ArcTan[a, b]], {a, b} ∈ Reals]` and look at the result for a full minute.

Comment: Wonderfull @J.M. I swapped a and b in my example. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Arg[(1 - E^2)*(2 I Pi k)]], k > 0]

(*  -(\[Pi]/2)  *)
```

Have fun!